# Absolute child not stretching to contents size inside a absolute parent

Tags: html, css

There are similar questions but none of them are helping me.

I have two divs. A child (a menu) and the parent(the floating bar). They're both positioned absolutely.

The scenario is, this is a floating bar that dynamically appears in different parts of the screen and it has to be stacked above everything else, hence why the parent is given a position absolute.

The child is a menu list that should also appear on top of every other element, fit it's size to it's content and appear when the you hover over it's sibling, a button thats on the floating toolbar.

```css
.floating-bar {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.button-menu {
  max-width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
}

.button {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 35px;
  height: 50px;
}

.button:hover + .button-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="floating-bar">
    <div class="button">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="button-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsm dolor sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsm dolor sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsm dolor sit amet</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now my problem is the content of the child element "button-menu" is not stretching to its content because of it's absolute parent. But I can't remove that positioning from the parent.

Is there another solution to achieve everything I want?

Requirements:

1. Need to be able to position the parent "floating-bar" anywhere on the screen and it should be placed on top of everything else.
2. The child, "button-menu" should also appear on top of everything, position itself to the bottom of the "button" and the content should stretch to it's max-width of 200px;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the style `width:max-content` to get desired full width of your container.

```css
.floating-bar {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.button-menu {
  max-width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  width: max-content;
  width: -moz-max-content;
}
.button {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 35px;
  height: 50px;
}
.button:hover + .button-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="floating-bar">
    <div class="button">A</div>
    <div class="button-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsm dolor sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsm dolor sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsm dolor sit amet</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow. I didn't know this. It's really cool. I hope the browser support is good enough for our app. We are targeting Safari 11 upwards. Thank you for suggesting this :)

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=max-content Be aware that it is still working draft only